# StringTokenizer в Java- Почему пропускает первое слово?

Tags: java

Почему при отправке строки answerLine- пропускается первое слово "answerList"

```
String answerLine="answerList--wer -- er-- 3333 - - fd - edfdf";

 StringTokenizer tokzer=new StringTokenizer(answerLine, "-{2}");
        while (tokzer.hasMoreTokens())
                  System.out.println(tokzer.nextToken().trim());
```

Вот результат

```
wer
er
3333

fd
edfdf
```

Comment: Не знаю почему у вас пропускает (и пропускает ли на самом деле?). У меня выводит. А ещё `StringTokenizer` устарел, и вместо него рекомендуется использовать метод `split` и `java.util.regex`.

Answer (score 2):

возможно вы где то случайно вызываете nextToken() лишний раз потому как приведенный тест ничего не пропускает

```
@Test
public void testST() throws Exception
{
    String answerLine = "answerList--wer -- er-- 3333 - - fd - edfdf";

    StringTokenizer tokzer = new StringTokenizer(answerLine, "-{2}");
    while(tokzer.hasMoreTokens())
        System.out.println(tokzer.nextToken().trim());
}
```

выдает:

```
answerList
wer
er
3333

fd
edfdf
```

однако обратите внимание на то что задать два минуса как разделитель не получится

```
@Test
public void testST2() throws Exception
{
    String answerLine = "each delimeter character - is independent {and} combining 2 charachers {is not} possible";

    StringTokenizer tokzer = new StringTokenizer(answerLine, "-{2}");
    while(tokzer.hasMoreTokens())
        System.out.println(tokzer.nextToken().trim());
}
```

выдаст:

```
each delimeter character
is independent
and
combining
charachers
is not
possible
```